# PDO fetching information from database

Tags: php

I've tried everything, the data that I am echoing out display directly after I hit submit, but once i refresh the page, it is gone. How can I echo out the data that is already stored in my database correctly? Here is my current code!

```
<h1>News Blog</h1>
<form method="POST">
    username: <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="name"><br />
    <textarea name="body" rows="10" cols="70"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['body'])){
        require'core/connect.php';

        //inserting data
        $query = dbConnect()->prepare("INSERT INTO blog (name, body) VALUES(?,?)");
        $query->bindParam(1, $_POST['name']);
        $query->bindParam(2, $_POST['body']);
        $query->execute();


        //getting data
        $stmt = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT name, body FROM blog WHERE name=:name AND body=:body");
        $stmt->execute();

        while($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo $rows['name'], '<br /><hr>';
            echo $rows['body'];
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Move your `//getting data` section *outside* of the `if` that checks for POST data?

Comment: I removed those, still same result.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed to bind parameters for the named placeholders `:name` and `:body` for your select query:

```
    //getting data
    $stmt = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT name, body FROM blog WHERE name=:name AND body=:body");

    // Add following two lines
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':body', $_POST['body'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();

    while($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo $rows['name'], '<br /><hr>';
        echo $rows['body'];
    }
```

Comment: That works, except when I refresh the page, the data does not display anymore.

Comment: Please combine this answer with @minitech's comment.  Also you want to `select` first and make sure the record does not exist before doing the `insert`.